# How to override styles for different resolutions in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to override styles in my application for 720 and 1080p. Now I declare resourcedictionaries in my page .xaml file:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/MapViewStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I want to redefine styles in page constructor like this:

```
public MapView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (ScreenSizeHelper.IsHd)
    {
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("/App;component/Styles/MapViewStyles.Hd.xaml", UriKind.Relative)});
    }
}
```

I checked in debug, that my dictionary was added to MergedDictionaries, but styles didn't override. How can I refresh MergedDictionaries or reinitialize page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I thought up some interesting solution. I create a special class named ResourceResolutionManager:

```
public class ResourceResolutionManager
{
    public static DependencyProperty ResolutionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Resolution", typeof(Resolutions?), typeof(ResourceResolutionManager),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null, ResolutionChanged));

    private static void ResolutionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null && (Resolutions)e.NewValue != ScreenExtension.CurrentResolution)
        {
            var dict = obj as ResourceDictionary;

            if (dict != null)
            {
                dict.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetResolution(DependencyObject obj, Resolutions? resolution)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ResolutionProperty, resolution);
    }

    public static Resolutions? GetResolution(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Resolutions?)obj.GetValue(ResolutionProperty);
    }
}
```

I determine screen resolution with my helper class:

```
public enum Resolutions { Wvga, Wxga, Hd };
public class ScreenExtension
{
    public static bool IsWvga
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsWxga
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsHd
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150;
        }
    }

    public static Resolutions CurrentResolution
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsWvga) return Resolutions.Wvga;
            if (IsWxga) return Resolutions.Wxga;
            if (IsHd) return Resolutions.Hd;

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution");
        }
    }
}
```

And I use ResourceResolutionManager in .xaml file this way:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Common.Hd.xaml">
    <core:ResourceResolutionManager.Resolution>
        <extensions1:Resolutions>Hd</extensions1:Resolutions>
    </core:ResourceResolutionManager.Resolution>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In ResourceResolutionManager I check if resolution match resolution in ResourceDictionary and if not I clear that ResourceDictionary.